# Python3 how to add string to integer within a list

Tags: string, python-3.x, list, int, addition

I am trying to calculate items within list, adding together string and integer.
Function does not work:

```
x_list = ['string', '100', 'string']

def calculate_str_and_int():
    str_x = x_list[1]
    sum_x = int(str_x) + 200
    print(sum_x)
```

Expected output:
    ['string', 300, 'string']

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should re-assign the value in position 1 to the newly calculated value, like e.g:

```
x_list = ['string', '100', 'string']

def calculate_str_and_int():
    str_x = x_list[1]
    sum_x = int(str_x) + 200
    x_list[1] = sum_x
    print(x_list)

calculate_str_and_int()
```

This will print:

```
['string', 300, 'string']
```